# Locking Eclipse to the Launcher Bar

Tags: 12.04, launcher, android, eclipse

Eclipse (from the Android Developers Bundle (ADB)) will lock to the launch bar, but then it is just an icon which cannot be opened.  I am running Ubuntu 12.04LTS.  Any idea how to fix this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recently went thru the same thing with a couple of programs (including Eclipse) that I had downloaded and ran locally from the user home directory via command line, but wanted a functional launcher icon to run from the desktop or dock.

This portion of the Ubuntu community docs pretty much covers everything you need.

[Unity Launchers and Desktop Files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)