# Dead link for Eclipes in the Ubuntu's launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, eclipse

I'm trying to lock Eclipse's icon to the launcher for a fast and easy access to it, using the simplest way of launching Eclipse, and then right clicking the Eclipse icon at the launcher and choosing "**Lock To Launcher**", and indeed when I then close Eclipse, its icon is locked in the launcher.
The problem is, when I then click the icon launcher to open Eclipse, the icon just flickers (blinks) for two or three times (meaning - it seems like it's gonna start), but then it stops and nothing happens - Eclipse won't open.
I might also mention that is seems like this is the only application I have this trouble with.
I tried to lock some other applications (like the calculator, for example), then close them and reopen, and they indeed were launched properly.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I've had this problem too. How did you install Eclipse?

Comment: It seems this problem depends on how you installed Eclipse. If you used Ubuntu Software Center or `apt-get` the icon should be fine. If you installed Eclipse using some other method in your personal folder, there may be a problem. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/346091/locking-eclipse-to-the-launcher-bar

Answer (score 0):

Create a file ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
Add this content, adjust the paths to your Eclipse/STS location:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=STS-3.5.1
Icon=spring_tool_suite.png
Path=/the/path/to/my/sts-3.5.1
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= /the/path/to/my/sts-3.5.1/STS
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Spring Tool Suite
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

Now open with nautilus:

```
user@host $ nautilus ~/.local/share/applications
```

Drag and drop the eclipse.desktop file to the unity launcer.